# How to draw a density (list) polar plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the function $P_{ns}$ which gives me the amplitude of a signal. The angles $\theta_B$ and $\phi_B$ are known. (25 and 180 for example)

```
    Subscript[P, NS][θ_, ϕ_] = 
  Sin[θ Degree]*Sin[ϕ Degree] *
    Cos[Subscript[θ, B]] - 
   Cos[θ Degree]*Sin[Subscript[θ, B]]*
     Sin[Subscript[ϕ, B]];
```

This function should be plotted in a polar plot similar to:
[image: ListPolarPlot with color given by a function of two variables] 
or to 
[image: the variable is plotted for a chosen theta value]

But in the second case, the color of the line does not change according to the given color function based on the $P_{ns}$ function, where $r$ is $\theta$ and $t$ is $\phi$.

```
    PolarPlot[{10*π/180, 20*π/180, 30*π/180, 40*π/180, 
     50*π/180, 60*π/180}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
      PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], 
       ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, r, t}, 
    Hue[Table[Subscript[Pnew, NS][i*10, j*10], {i, 6}, {j, 36}]]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

Comment: What is $Pnew_{NS}$?

Comment: The initial function is zero. That's a fundamental problem, I guess..

Comment: @Rom38 The function is 0 only for **ϕ** =0 and 180.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork **PnewNS** is basically the same function after changing the coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood the question of the topic starter, she needs to plot the `ContourPlot` of the function that is defined by polar coordinates.
My solution is done for very similar (but of course, nonzero function):

```
pns[θ_, ϕ_] := Sin[ϕ]*Cos[θ] - Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ];

ContourPlot[
 pns[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], Arg[x + I*y]], {x, -π, π}, {y, -π, π}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 9]]
```

[image]

Comment: Please insert code in a format that can be copied and evaluated as-is.  I have edited your post for you this time as an example.

Comment: How did you do the Greec letters in code wrappers? I was trying to do it but without success..

Comment: To make them pretty use [halirutan's toolbar buttons](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1044/121), but if you don't it is better to leave them as e.g. `\[Theta]` which will copy and paste correctly.

Comment: Problem is that I don't need to plot the density for all the values of **θ** , but only for some specific values, like 10, 20 degrees, etc..

Comment: You can to the same as I did, but first make a `Table` from your function like dat=Table[pns[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], Arg[x + I*y]], {x, -π, π,step}, {y, -π, π,step}], using the step value what you need. After this you can use the `ListContourPlot[dat,<options>]` to plot it. Just remove the `PlotPoints` instruction